# When rotating the terrain how can i make it to remember the last position of the rotation?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

In the top of the code in Game1.cs I have:

```
private float angle = 0f;
private float angleRightLeft = 0f;
private float angleUpDown = 0f;
private bool rotationDirection;
private int terrainWidth = 4;
private int terrainHeight = 3;
private float[,] heightData;
```

In the draw method I have this code:

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
    device.Clear(Color.Black);
    RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
    rs.CullMode = CullMode.None;
    rs.FillMode = FillMode.WireFrame;
    device.RasterizerState = rs;
    if (rotationDirection == true)
    {
        worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Left, 
                                                 angleRightLeft);
        worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f,
                                               0,
                                               terrainHeight / 2.0f) *
                                               Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleRightLeft);
    }
    else
    {
        worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f,
                                               0,
                                               terrainHeight / 2.0f) *
                                               Matrix.CreateRotationX(angleUpDown);
    }
    effect.CurrentTechnique = effect.Techniques["ColoredNoShading"];
    effect.Parameters["xView"].SetValue(viewMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["xProjection"].SetValue(projectionMatrix);
    effect.Parameters["xWorld"].SetValue(worldMatrix);
}
```

And the keys process input method :

```
private void ProcessInput(float amount)
{
    previousState = currentState;
    currentState = Mouse.GetState();
    Vector3 moveVector = new Vector3(0 , 0 , 0);
    KeyboardState keyState = Keyboard.GetState();
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
    {
        angleUpDown += 0.05f;
        rotationDirection = false;
    }

    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
    {
        angleUpDown -= 0.05f;
        rotationDirection = false;
    }

    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
    {
        angleRightLeft += 0.05f;
        rotationDirection = true;
    }

    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
    {
        angleRightLeft -= 0.05f;
        rotationDirection = true;
    }

    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Z))
        cameraPosition += new Vector3(0, -1, 0);
    if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
    {
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        this.graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
        this.graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }
    if (this.graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth < 1920)
    {
       /*
       if (WasMouseLeftClick())
       {
           changeScreenNode(this.graphics, 1920, 1080, true);
       }*/

       if (WasDoubleClick())
       {
           changeScreenNode(this.graphics, 1920, 1080, true);
       }
    }

    if (WasMouseLeftClick())
    {
        previousClick = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

And the update method:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    fpsm.Update();
    float timeDifference = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0f;
    ProcessInput(timeDifference);
    modelRotation += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds *
                            MathHelper.ToRadians(0.1f);
    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

The problem is that when I press the D button and rotate the terrain to the right if stop pressing D and press on W to rotate the terrain up then the terrain first move back to its original position.

I want that it will stay on the position it was after I pressed on D or A or S or W and when I click on another key it will continue from there and not reset to its original position first.

I think I need to change something in the draw method.

How can I make that it when I click on a key and then on another key it will rotate from the position it stopped and not return/reset to its original position first ?

EDIT**

This is what i did in the draw method:

```
if (rotationDirection == true)
            {
                worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Left, angleRightLeft);
                worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleRightLeft);
                oldPosition = worldMatrix;
            }
            else
            {
                worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(angleUpDown);
                oldPosition = worldMatrix;
            }
```

oldPosition is type Matrix.
Then in the keys process method i did on each pressed key: worldMatrix = oldPosition;

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up) || keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
            {
                angleUpDown += 0.05f;
                rotationDirection = false;
                worldMatrix = oldPosition;
            }
```

But its still not working good .
What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Why not throw the current position into another variable after its finished rotating? Then when you press the other button you can just return to that "old" position?

Comment: sab669 please look at my question on the bottom i just updated it added what i changed tried to do what you said. But its not working good yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am reading your question right you want to keep previous rotation when changing the input direction. If this is the case you can achieve this by Replacing this:

```
if (rotationDirection == true)
        {
            worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateFromAxisAngle(this.rotation.Left, angleRightLeft);
            worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleRightLeft);
            oldPosition = worldMatrix;
        }
        else
        {
            worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(angleUpDown);
            oldPosition = worldMatrix;
        }
```

with this

```
worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateRotationX(angleUpDown) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(angleLeftRight);
```

Your existing code did only used one axis rotation matrix at a time. If you changed directions on the next update/draw it would reset the previous axis to zero. The updated code above utilized both values. In addition to this you could also use Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll like so (I may have ordering wrong here so double check it):

```
worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-terrainWidth / 2.0f, 0, terrainHeight / 2.0f) * Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(angleUpDown, angleLeftRight, 0);
```